# Should "merge commit" be merged back into the dev branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-request

We use Gitlab for our project, and we have two long-lived branches: dev and master, similar to the Git Flow. And We're using the "merge commit" method, which will create a merge commit in the master branch.

However, the master branch will always ahead of the dev branch because of those "merge commit".

[image]

so, my question is, should I merge those "merge commit" back to the dev branch? And Why?

Comment: 1) you don't merge a _commit_ in `master` to the `dev` branch, you merge the entire branch, and 2) Yes, you need to do this to keep `dev` updated with the latest changes from `master`.  You don't have much of a choice for 2) given that you are using a merge-based workflow.

Answer (score 3):

> Should “merge commit” be merged back into the dev branch?

No, unless you want `dev` to get changes from master (which could have been modified from other branches, like an hotfix)

If `dev` is long-lived, you merge it to `master`, but you don't merge `master` to `dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dev branch like the master branch ? If you want to have a branch based on the master, you can use :

$ git checkout -b branchname master

Or if you want to update a branch with the master branch, you can use :

$ git merge branchToUpdate master